# Interface V/s Abstract in Method calling c#

Tags: c#

In the code below if manager class does not inherit abstract class "customer" and if i use override keyword in "display" method then it gives an error "Manager.Display()': no suitable method found to override". But on the other hand ,if "manager" class inherit both interface and abstract class, the "display" method with override keyword not giving any error.How it comes,which method it calls either interface or abstract.why it not gives error.please see the code below ..

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    void Display();
}
public abstract class Customer
{
    public abstract void Display();
}
public class Manager : Customer,IEmployee
{
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dsds");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Manager c = new Manager();
        c.Display();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `override` if you're not inheriting from a base class - what would you be overriding?  And you cannot override interface methods -- those are just contract methods that must be declared.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `override` if you're wanting to extend or modify the implementation of a base class.  You cannot override interface methods -- those are just contract methods that must be declared.

From MSDN:

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or
>   virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or
>   event.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx